# Javascript to clear RadTextBox onFocus

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to clear RadTextBox data onfocus()....

My code is:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtNewActivity" onfocus="clearContents(this);" Text="New activity description..." runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></telerik:RadTextBox>
```

My Javascript is:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    function clearContents(element) {
        $("#txtNewActivity").text='';
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
onfocus="if(this.value=='New activity description...') this.value=''"
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='New activity description...'"
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I used texbox "EmptyMessage" property for this.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to pass the value to function just clear it in there itself...Try this

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtNewActivity" onfocus="this.value='';" Text="New activity description..." runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

$("[id$=txtNewActivity]").val('');

As it is a server control, i don't think it can be accessed the way you have written.

Thanks!!